# Selecting different nodes with Xpath

Tags: xml, xpath

I have an XML file in the following format. I want to select the `home` nodes which has a `record` `type 1` and `gender 1`.

I am trying to do it like

```
/root/home/record[type=01]
```

But don't know how to include the rest. Is it ever possible to select what I want using simply XPath?

```
<home>
  <record>
    <type>01</type>
  </record>
  <record>
    <gender>01</gender>
  </record>
</home>

<home>
  <record>
    <type>01</type>
  </record>
  <record>
    <gender>02</gender>
  </record>
</home>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes selection part should be your XPATH and only conditions should come in bracket:

`/root/home[record/gender='01' and record/type='01']`